Will the divergent section of the tube generate pressure below atmospheric pressure?
I noticed the Venturi tube, which is said to generate pressure below atmospheric pressure. It has a convergence section and a divergence section, and I believe that the convergence section will gradually reduce the pressure, but it will not result in a pressure lower than atmospheric pressure. Once the fluid enters the divergent section, it will generate a pressure lower than atmospheric pressure. So if a tube only has a divergence section and no convergence section, will it also generate pressure lower than atmospheric pressure?
I am saying that the fluid in the divergent section is discharged into an open space.



it will not result in a pressure lower than atmospheric pressure

Yes, it can ($\sim$ cit.)
Example
I suspect you've never dealt with an old motor-bike or with a carburetor, that device needed to add fuel to intake air from a non-pressurized tank, by means of the suction produced low pressure at the throat of a Venturi tube.
Some physics and math
Are we talking about a nearly incompressible regime, or at least a subsonic one? If so,

in the convergent section: velocity increases, pressure decreases;
at throat, the velocity is maximum and pressure is minimum
in the divergence section: velocity decreases and pressure increases

At least for the incompressible regime with constant density, the pressure you reach at throat depends on the pressure at the inflow, the velocity at inflow and the area ratio as
$$P_2 = P_1 - \frac{1}{2} \rho U_1^2 \left[ \left(\frac{A_1}{A_2}\right)^2 - 1 \right]$$
using continuity and Bernoulli (with reasonable assumptions)
$$\begin{cases} 
U_1 A_1 = U_2 A_2 \\
P_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho U_1^2 = P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho U_2^2
\end{cases}
$$
So, as an example, if inlet pressure is atmospheric pressure $P_1 = P_{atm}$, pressure at throat is lower than $P_{atm}$.

I am saying that the fluid in the divergent section is discharged into an open space. The pressure in open spaces is atmospheric pressure. So your answer seems to be problematic. The pressure in the divergent section should gradually increase to atmospheric pressure.

So what? what's the problem in discharging at atmospheric pressure? If the Venturi pipe is symmetric, outflow velocity goes back to the inflow velocity value and outlow pressure goes back to inflow pressure value $P_{atm}$, after ahving reached $V_{max}$ and $P_{min}<P_{atm}$ at throat.

I can't understand what you think it's problematic

The pressure in the Venturi tube is lower than atmospheric pressure, why is the divergent tube not lower than atmospheric pressure here?

For incompressible or compressible subsonic flows, velocity decreases and pressure increases in the divergent section. Do we agree on this?

That's when the pressure increases to atmospheric pressure. My pipe has no convergence section, only a divergence section. The upstream pipes are of equal diameter and have a constant diameter. The upstream pressure cannot be lower than atmospheric pressure.

@enbin If you have atmospheric pressure at both the input and output, what drives the flow?

@JohnDoty neglecting losses, it's a feasible condition: a current is already in motion and finds a Venturi pipe on its way. If you think using relative motion, grab a small Venturi pipe with you hand while you're walking at constant speed, you get such a condition

@basics Then there's ram pressure at the inlet.

@JohnDoty The pressure upstream of the pipe is definitely higher than atmospheric pressure. For example, when using a compressor to transport compressed air, the pressure upstream of the pipe is definitely higher than atmospheric pressure. Assuming that the diameter of the upstream pipe is constant. For example, pipes with a diameter of 100 centimeters.

@basics The pressure upstream of the pipe is definitely higher than atmospheric pressure. For example, when using a compressor to transport compressed air, the pressure upstream of the pipe is definitely higher than atmospheric pressure. Assuming that the diameter of the upstream pipe is constant. For example, pipes with a diameter of 100 centimeters.
